# Input variable for terraform provider version

Tags: terraform

In a CI/CD context, I would like to define provider versions outside my terraform configuration using `TF_VAR_` [environment variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#environment-variables).

I'm trying to use input variable to set the version of helm provider in `versions.tf` (terraform 0.12) but it seems not allowed :

```
Error: Invalid provider_requirements syntax

  on versions.tf line 3, in terraform:
   3:     helm = "${var.helm_version}"

provider_requirements entries must be strings or objects.


Error: Variables not allowed

  on versions.tf line 3, in terraform:
   3:     helm = "${var.helm_version}"

Variables may not be used here.
```

How can I configure this ?

If it's not possible, how I can manage the terraform provider version outside my configuration ?

Comment: Have you tried doing this in a required providers block?

Comment: Not yet but I don't think it's the best way to do as in version 0.13 [Terraform requires explicit source information for any providers that are not HashiCorp-maintained](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-13.html#explicit-provider-source-locations)

Comment: Damn, I don't think it's possible to achieve what you're after then after reading through the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Cannot be done. I wish it could be done. `terraform init` resolves and downloads the providers, you won't have access to variables at that point.

> Each terraform block can contain a number of settings related to
> Terraform's behavior. Within a terraform block, only constant values
> can be used; arguments may not refer to named objects such as
> resources, input variables, etc, and may not use any of the Terraform
> language built-in functions.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/terraform.html

Answer (score 1):

As @thekbb says, it's not possible to get access to version variable during `terraform init` at least in `0.12.20`. However, I've below workaround to manage providers outside your configuration.

You could use `alias` with provider configuration to achieve this. Let's assume you want `1.3.0` version of `helm`. Rather than passing it as a var, you could define it statically with an alias like below.

```
provider "helm" {
  alias = "helm-stable"
  version = "1.3.0" (the version you pass via TF_VAR_helm_version)
  kubernetes {
    host     = "https://104.196.242.174"
    username = "ClusterMaster"
    password = "MindTheGap"

    client_certificate     = file("~/.kube/client-cert.pem")
    client_key             = file("~/.kube/client-key.pem")
    cluster_ca_certificate = file("~/.kube/cluster-ca-cert.pem")
  }
}
```

Then, in your `resource` or `data` providers, you could point to a particular provider like below::

```
data "some_ds" "example" {
  name = "dummy"
  provider = helm.helm-stable
}
```

For more details, refer to the below links::

- [providers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html)
- [allow variable in provider field](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11578)